# Does the group of reals embed into some ultrapower of the rationals?

Tags: group-theory, logic, abelian-groups, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

It is well-known that $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ are elementarily equivalent as ordered sets, but how about their group structure? Are they elementarily equivalent as groups? Or more specifically, does $\mathbb R$ embed into some ultrapower of $\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are elementarily equivalent - this can be shown via Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games (where we switch from the group structures to their corresponding relational versions - replace the group operation and the inverse operation with the relations defining their graphs). And by the Keisler-Shelah ultrapower theorem, this means that they have isomorphic ultrapowers (so since $\mathbb{R}$ embeds into all its ultrapowers, $\mathbb{R}$ embeds into some ultrapower of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis) for $\mathbb{R}$ and send each element $r$ of the basis to the hyperrational $\frac{\lfloor{r}{H}\rfloor}{H}$, where $H$ is a fixed infinite hypernatural.

In fact the map $r\mapsto \lfloor{r}{H}\rfloor$ embeds the additive group of the reals into the ultrapower of the *integers*.